# select bottleneck and insert into select doesn't work on cockroach db

Tags: bulkinsert, cockroachdb

I have to union 2 tables like below query. and 'table2' has 15GB data. But it show errors. I set max-sql-memory=.80 and I don't know how to solve this. 
When I execute this query **with limit 50000 option**, it works! 
Even 'select * from table2' shows same error.
I think there are a select bottleneck somehow....
Also, with this query it is unusual only 1 of 3nodes's latency goes up. (AWS EC2 i3.xlarge type)

▶ Query
insert into table1 (
  InvoiceID, PayerAccountId, LinkedAccountId, RecordType, RecordId, ProductName
  )
select 
  InvoiceID, PayerAccountId, LinkedAccountId, RecordType, RecordId, ProductName
from table2;

▶ Error : 
driver: bad connection
warning: connection lost!
opening new connection: all session settings will be lost

▶ Log : 
 W180919 04:59:20.452985 186 storage/raft_transport.go:465  [n3] raft transport stream to node 2 failed: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
W180919 04:59:20.452996 190 vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:1158  grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {10.240.98.xxx:26257 0  }. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing cannot reuse client connection". Reconnecting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're using a single statement to read ~15GB of data from `table2` and insert it into `table1`. Unfortunately, as you've discovered this won't work. See [limits for a single statement](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.0/known-limitations.html#write-and-update-limits-for-a-single-statement) which covers exactly this scenario. Setting `--max-sql-memory=.80` will not help and most likely will hurt as CockroachDB needs some breathing room as our memory tracking is not precise. The "bad connection warning" and the error you found in the logs are both symptoms which occur when a Cockroach process has crashed, presumably due to running out of memory.

If you need to copy the data from `table2` to `table1` transactionally then you're a bit out of luck at this time. While you could try using an explicit transaction and breaking the single `INSERT` statement into multiple statements, you'll very likely run into transaction size limits. If you can handle performing the copy non-transactionally then I'd suggest breaking the `INSERT` into pieces. Something along the lines of:

`INSERT INTO table1 (...)
     SELECT ... FROM table2 WHERE InvoiceID > $1 LIMIT 10000
  RETURNING InvoiceID`

The idea here is that you copy in 10k row batches. You would use the `RETURNING InvoiceID` clause to track the last `InvoiceID` that was copied and start the next insert from there.